# Interpolation of point data gives no data values in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, raster, point, interpolation, tin

I am for the moment, quite stumped. I have a layer of points to which i have retrieved values from an underlying raster. From these values, I am trying to create a TIN, using the Interpolation tool in QGIS. The tool runs with no errors, but the result is a raster of no data. I have tried:

Using QGIS 2.18 (Las Palmas de G.C:) and running Windows 10

- Setting the regional settings to using a period and a comma for the decimal marker
- Different tools, including IDW and squared TIN in the Interpolation dialog. This includes SAGA Trinagulation tool (this returns an error - tool not found)
- Different projections for the points and the raster
- Opening the points and running the analysis in a separate project
- Changing the directories to avoid spacces in directory names
- Changing the output file type (.asc and .tif)
- Running the interpolation in an older version of QGIS (2.8)

Nothing has worked so far. The only diference was using squared TIN, that produced values of 0 instead of No data.

EDIT: here's a screencap showing the points and a sample of the attribute table. Second column is the data used, it's the same as the first with negative nubmers set to 0.

[image: Point data]

Any ideas?

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the point data that you have.

Comment: @Sampi I'm trying to reason why one might want to produce a TIN in this way when there are generally more tools and workflows available (or at least comparable) for rasters. I've used workflows pulling out raster values to points too, but this is only when the points were the end game. There are better ways to resample or dump resolution in the original raster, if that's what's needed. Also, I wouldn't recommend mismatching projections.

Comment: I made a simple test by digitizing 4 points with attribute "syvyys" varying between 80.1m and 80.4. Running interpolation with QGIS 2.16 by using the TIN method worked as supposed. I used the default output size and "Set to current extent". You must add more details into your question.

Comment: @Priscilla: thanks, you're right that dumping resolution or resampling would be more efficient in another manner, but that's not what I'm after. I'm extracting values to create a wholly different raster, which is dependent on the specific points I'm using.  I'ts a method under development.

Comment: @user 30184: sure, I'll add more detail. What is it you need to know?

Comment: All that others need to know for reproducing your case.

Comment: All righty then. All that others need to know. I tried to do this already, and I do not know what information is missing. I'm not at liberty to reveal everything about this case, but if there's some specific thing that is missing, please tell me.

Comment: I do not ask to reveal confidential data. Any point data should do. Like "Let's take this CSV file with 4 points and one attribute (data are here inline). I converted CSV into layer in QGIS by doing this and that. Then I used the interpolation tool, selected my test layer and attribute for interpolation, pressed the Add button to add it into the list, selected TIN as method, used the default output size 300 by 300 pixels, pressed Set to current extents (or to extent that you'll give), pointed output into file xxx.tif". With that method I am getting good result.

Comment: @Sampi Usually interpolation is pretty straight forward, so I'm trying to think of things that interpolators might struggle with. Do your extracted points contain zeros, negative numbers, nulls, or anything that seems strange? I would label your point values and zoom into several areas to make sure that the points accurately reflect the raster, and pay special attention to anything strange. What is your spread of values (max/min)? Are there huge leaps of values right next to each other? Is your point density very high or very low? Are your points in a regular grid or more random?

Comment: The range is from 0 (or slightly negative) to about 113. No really strange values or sudden jumps. Zeros are expected, should those ber a problem? I can run a raster calculator and add something to each value if that might work. You can look at the point distribution in the above image: it's quite dense, but random.

Comment: I tried that, no dice. Then I tried a set of random points with random values between 0 and 113 in the same are - worked perfectly. So this is surely an input issue. I'll be looking at my data closely now.

Comment: I spent today tracking this problem. It lies within the point data. I was able to interpolate using a like-sized random point data set that I had extracted the raster values to, but not using the same point data to which I had added a random values (with a similar range of values). So what could be the cause? Points too close together? Something else?